# Changing style elements based on cell contents

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table, like so:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using Javascript, how can I search the table and change a style element (e.g. `backgroundColor`) based on the contents of a cell (e.g. make the background color of all cells with the word 'one' in them red)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CjW77/)

```
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for(var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];

    //get the text from the first child node - which should be a text node
    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 

    //check for 'one' and assign this table cell's background color accordingly 
    if (currentText === "one")
        node.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! I would have responded sooner but I had to yell at OpenDNS.

Answer (score 8):

Here's code that searches the table and sets the background color of all cells who's contents is "one".  I assume you can adapt this to check for other values:

```
var cells = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    if (cells[i].innerHTML == "one") {
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

with this HTML:

```
<table id="test">
  <tr>
    <td>one</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>three</td>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Uubqg/

Answer (score 1):

Use `getElementsByTagName()` to return the cells, and match the words in their `innerText` property:

```
var tds = document.getElementById("table-id").getElementsByTagName("td");
var num_tds = tds.length;
for (var i = 0; i < num_tds; i++) {
  if (tds[i].innerText.indexOf("one") > -1) {
    tds[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

Note: This will match the word "one" anywhere in the cell.

[Here it is in action on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/x2m7j/)

Answer (score 0):

Also, a [jQuery](http://jquery.com) example (for full picture)

```
$.each($('td'), function () {
  if($(this).html() == 'one') {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
  }
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ulexub

Answer (score 0):

Why use Javascript to do this? Instead deliver the table with the cells having the appropriate class e.g.

```
<td class="oneCell">One</td>
```

Then simply use CSS to style the contents as you see fit.

If you really need to use Javascript you need to look into DOM. There are various references on line, for example http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domstructure

Comment: Why use Javascript to do this? Because sometimes you don't know what's going to be in the table cell, or what you want to search for. For instance, letting the user search the table and highlighting the cells that match the input text.

Comment: Really - Some part of the server or Javascript needs to put the data into the cell - hence able to set the class.

Comment: But you can't concoct a class name for every possible cell value.

Comment: Example (based on [Adam Rackis's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8722719/398242)): http://jsfiddle.net/CjW77/1/

Comment: Yes you can - There is a finite number of cells. Just number them e.g. cell1 cell2 .... But the question implies that the person wants all cells with a particular value to have a style. The solution I have given with the use of Javascript is both easier and also works for people that do not have javascript enabled.

Comment: "Just number them e.g. cell1 cell2" - this does nothing to aid in finding a cell by it's text content.

Comment: When you place the value into the cell you simply change the class name at the same time.This will then change its appearance even if Javascript is not enabled on the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a dynamic solution based on value and did this

```
    $('.dataframe td').each(function(){
        var num = parseFloat($(this).text());
        if (num > 0) {
            $(this).addClass('success');
            //$(this).css('color','Green');
        } else if (num < 0) {
            $(this).addClass('danger');
            //$(this).css('color','Red');
        }
    });
```