# Based on td value need to do color in html

Tags: html, css

I have HTML table. Based on td value i need to change the color of cells. Below is the table:

how to check and apply the condition on td value.

```
ent<table border="1">
<tr bgcolor="#6699FF">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>DOJ</th>
    <th>BAU</th>
<tr>
    <td>Rahul</td>
    <td>Jan</td>
    <td>z</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Ravi</td>
    <td>Feb</td>
    <td>z</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you'll need to use javascript.

Comment: `bgcolor="#6699FF"` - Obsolete since HTML5 ([Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)) - Use css `<tr style="background-color: #6699FF">`

Comment: how to add the condition in inline css

Comment: you want to change "color" or "background color"? inline css syntax is `<td style="background: red; color: white;">red background and white text</td>`

Comment: both color and background but based on td value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing style elements based on cell contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722680/changing-style-elements-based-on-cell-contents)

Answer (score 2):

JS would be your best bet. Here is the JS code that will work for your situation:

```
td_array = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
check_value = "Rahul";

for (i = 0; i < td_array.length; i++){
  if (td_array[i].textContent == check_value){
    td_array[i].style.color = "red";
  };
};
```

This code loops through your **td** elements and if the td text matches your **check_value** then it colors the text of that td red.

You can find the working JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/darkisa/36ogjayb/

Comment: Just follow the JSFiddle link and you will have all the code.

Comment: i am sending this output in email and JScode is not reading in email, can you provide the condition in html only

Comment: You cannot do it with pure HTML. You will need to use JavaScript for the conditional, but you can put JavaScript code in your HTML. Just put your JavaScript code in the between the <script> elements e.g. <script> *JavaScript code* </script>

Comment: After adding <script> tag it's showing colors but whenever we are sending in email it's not coming

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you need to use javascript to get the values. HTML by itself is static. JS is a scripting language that dynamically changes the content like you are wanting. In this answer I am using jquery as its common. If you just want to loop through the tab and assign a color based on value to each cell use this:

```
var cell = $('td'); 

cell.each(function() { //loop through all td elements ie the cells

var cell_value = $(this).html(); //get the value

if (cell_value == 1) //if then for if value is 1
    $(this).css({'background' : 'red'});   // changes td to red.
});
```

So from there you just need add to the if then or switch to a switch statement. Hope that helps you! If you only care about a certain cell(s) then assign it a class then just use this code:

```
var cell = $('.CLASSNAMEHERE'); 

cell.each(function() { //loop through all td elements ie the cells

var cell_value = $(this).html(); //get the value

if (cell_value == 1) //if then for if value is 1
    $(this).css({'background' : 'red'});   // changes td to red.
});
```

If you want to highlight the whole row use this code:

```
 $(this).parent().css({'background' : 'red'});   // changes row to red.
```