# How to color td in table using the specified value?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm using PHP to fetch all records from the database, I have TicketID, TicketNo, TicketStatus display on the HTML page using the table. Now I want the value of TicketStatus to be red color if the value is 'Closed for reservation' otherwise if the value is 'Open for reservation' will be color green.

Comment: What do you mean by “it did not work”? Did you get an error?

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the answer you are looking for [Changing style elements based on cell contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722680/changing-style-elements-based-on-cell-contents).

Here is a modified version of the original code that will give you what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/yf1e72pq/

```
var allTableCells = document.getElementsByClassName("ticketStatus");
for(var i = 0, max = allTableCells.length; i < max; i++) {
    var node = allTableCells[i];

    //get the text from the first child node - which should be a text node
    var currentText = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue; 

    //check for 'Closed for reservation' and assign this table cell's color accordingly 
    if (currentText === "Closed for reservation")
        node.style.color = "red";
}
```