# Use rowStyle for bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table and I would like to color certain columns red or green based on the value that they are having.

I am having the following table:

```js
function ajaxRequest(params) {
  var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'
  $.get(url + '?' + $.param(params.data)).then(function(res) {
    params.success(res)
    console.log(res)
  })
}


function rowStyle(row, index) {

  if (row.trx_type.includes("Purchase")) {
    return {
      css: {
        'background-color': 'lightcoral';
      }
    }
  }

  if (row.trx_type.includes("Sale")) {
    return {
      css: {
        'background-color': 'lightgreen';
      }
    }
  }
}


function BuySellFormatter(value, row, index) {

  if (row.title.includes("et")) {
    return "Purchase"
  }
  return "Sale"

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<h2>Products</h2>

<table id="table_2" data-toggle="table" data-height="1200" data-page-size="50" data-ajax="ajaxRequest" data-pagination="true" data-row-style="rowStyle" class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="userId" scope="col">userId</th>
      <th data-field="id" scope="col">id</th>
      <th data-field="title" scope="col">title</th>
      <th data-field="completed" scope="col" data-formatter="BuySellFormatter">Buy/Sell</th>
      <th data-field="completed" scope="col">completed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Is there a way to style each row like the following:

[image]

I am using `rowStyle` to apply my style, however, as you can see above the css is not correctly applied.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: You can use jquery to achieve it Check this https://infoheap.com/jquery-change-table-cells-color-based-on-values/

Comment: Check also this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722680/changing-style-elements-based-on-cell-contents

Comment: Thx! Why is my current way not working?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data-field, there's no property for trx_type therefore in your rowStyle function, the row.trx_type will be undefined.

You can achieve the effect similar to your BuySellFormatter method, by accessing the title property.

```js
function ajaxRequest(params) {
  var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos'
  $.get(url + '?' + $.param(params.data)).then(function(res) {
    params.success(res)
    console.log('res', res)
  })
}

function rowStyle(row, index) {
  if (row.title.includes("et")) {
    return {
      css: {
        'background-color': 'lightcoral'
      }
    }
  } else {
    return {
      css: {
        'background-color': 'lightgreen'
      }
    }
  }
}



function BuySellFormatter(value, row, index) {

  if (row.title.includes("et")) {
    return "Purchase"
  }
  return "Sale"

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.18.3/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<h2>Products</h2>

<table id="table_2" data-toggle="table" data-height="1200" data-page-size="50" data-ajax="ajaxRequest" data-pagination="true" data-row-style="rowStyle" class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="userId" scope="col">userId</th>
      <th data-field="id" scope="col">id</th>
      <th data-field="title" scope="col">title</th>
      <th data-field="buysell" scope="col" data-formatter="BuySellFormatter">Buy/Sell</th>
      <th data-field="completed" scope="col">completed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: [Fiddle here link](https://jsfiddle.net/hayyi_z/mwv1kcsf/39/)